# How to edit and delete records of MySQL database without refreshing?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am new to ajax, I am trying to view, add, edit and delete data of mysql database without refreshing the tab or in other words using ajax on this table:

[image]

I have done the view part, *edited but I can not figure out how to edit or delete *. I know it is a very long task, but I have found no solution on the internet.. Thanks in advance

HTML Code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>View Data Without refresh</title>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery-git.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function() {
           (function() {                
              $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "display.php",             
                 dataType: "html",               
                 success: function(response){                    
                 $("#responsecontainer").html(response); 
                 }
              });
           });
        });
</script>

</head>

<body>
        <fieldset><br>
            <legend>Manage Student Details</legend>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Class</th>
                    <th>Section</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                </tr>
            </table>
             <div id="responsecontainer" align="center"></div>                    
        </fieldset>
        <input type="button" id="display" value="Add New"/>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP Display Code:

```
<?php
include("connection.php");

$sql = "select * from tbl_demo";
$result=mysqli_query($db,$sql);
echo "<table class='myTable'>";
while($data = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
{   
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td width='13.5%'>$data[0]</td>";
echo "<td width='21%'>$data[1]</td>";
echo "<td width='19.5%'>$data[2]</td>";
echo "<td width='24%'>$data[3]</td>";
echo "<td><span class='edit'>Edit</span> | <span 
class='delete'>Delete</span></td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: I'm not seeing a button. Your ajax code is set to run after the document has loaded. Your question title is very vague. What exactly are you asking here? What's the *specific* problem you have?

Comment: I can't understand question too..

Comment: there are 'Edit | Delete' two span used in the 'Status' table heading, if user clicks Edit, the data should be edited or if User clicks Delete, the data should be deleted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `connection`, `sql query` and `php response` is ok and

> I want it to be automatically done

means you want run ajax on page loading. Then, Output of php should be at last instead in each iteration.

```
<?php
    include("connection.php");

    $sql = "select * from tbl_demo";
    $result=mysqli_query($db,$sql);
    $output = "<table class='myTable'>";
    while($data = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
    {   
        $output .="<tr>";
        $output .="<td width='13.5%'>$data[0]</td>";
        $output .="<td width='21%'>$data[1]</td>";
        $output .="<td width='19.5%'>$data[2]</td>";
        $output .="<td width='24%'>$data[3]</td>";
        $output .="<td><span class='edit'>Edit</span> | <span 
        class='delete'>Delete</span></td>";
        $output .="</tr>";
    }
    $output .="</table>";
    echo $output;
?>
```

To make edit/delete you need to pass or redirect page with action to other page named controller. After making changes again you need to redirect `index/view data` page or use ajax if you don't want to refresh/redirect page.

Comment: @HaseebHassy : if you want all CRUD operation via ajax means no page refresh then yes all things will be in the javascript.